# Creating stacked chart in Altair with multiple axes and gaps

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I am trying to create a chart depicting two different processes on the same timescale in Altair. Here is an example in excel

[image: Here is an example]

I have generated the stacked horizontal bar chart below in excel using the following data. The numbers in red are offsets/gaps, not to be displayed in the final plot. Nothing special about these numbers, please feel free to use any other set of numbers.

[image]

The numbers in red are offsets and
I would have posted an attempt, but I am completely out of my depth guessing what functionality to begin with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question! Could you add some sample data to your question, preferably in the form of a pandas data frame?

Comment: Hi @jakevdp - Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might make a chart like this, using a conditional opacity to hide the offset values:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'axis': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'value': [0.5, 0.9, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0.8, 1, 1.4, 1.1, 4.1, 0.3, 1.1],
    'label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', None, 'C', None, 'F', 'G']
})

alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('axis:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[2, 1])),
    x='value:Q',
    color=alt.Color('label:N', legend=None),
    opacity=alt.condition('isValid(datum.label)', alt.value(1), alt.value(0)),
    order=alt.Order('index:Q', sort='ascending')
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @jakevdp, thanks for this amazing answer. I wanted the second axis to have different color than the first, but hopefully I can make it work. Thanks again.